# When a set of consecutive numbers can be covered by differences between distinct integers?

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-number-theory, arithmetic-combinatorics

I will start with an example. Suppose that I would like to cover the set $\{1,2,3\}$ by differences between three integers $m_1,\ m_2$ and $m_3$ in the following sense:
$$
\{1,2,3\}=\{m_2-m_1,m_3-m_2,m_3-m_1\}.
$$
This is possible by taking $m_1=1,m_2=2$ and $m_3=4$.

I take another example: the equality
$$
\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}=\{m_2-m_1,m_3-m_1,m_3-m_2,m_4-m_1,m_4-m_2,m_4-m_3\}
$$
is satisfied for $m_1=1,m_2=2,m_3=5,m_4=7$.

Now I can formulate the problem to which, hopefully, someone can help me to arrive to the solution:

(a) Find the set of all positive integers $n\ge 2$ (or, at least, an infinite subset) for which there exist integers $m_1,\dots,m_n$ such that 
$$
\{m_j-m_i\}_{1\le i<j\le n}=\Bigl\{1,2,\dots,\frac{(n-1)n}{2}\Bigr\}.
$$

.

As regarding the case $n=5$, I was able to prove that it is not possible to find a sequence of $5$ integers such that their differences cover the set $\{1,2,\dots,10\}$. It turns out that in this case the best possible scenario is to cover the set from $1$ to $11$ in which $6$ is missing:
$$
\{1,2,3,4,5,7,8,9,10,11\}=\{m_j-m_i\}_{1\le i<j\le 5}.
$$
A solution here is: $m_1=1,m_2=2,m_3=5,m_4=10,m_5=12$.

This last remark led to the second question:

(b) For each $n\ge 2$ find an increasing finite sequence $m_1,\dots,m_n$ of integers such that the set $\{m_j-m_i\}_{1\le i<j\le n}$ has $\frac{n(n-1)}{2}$ elements (the differences are distinct) and $m_n-m_1$ is minim.

I realize that these problems can be very difficult. I will be satisfied with partial solutions or, at least, ideas on how to proceed. Thank you!

Comment: Are you having difficulty finding this set and that sequence?  Do you have a specific question?

Comment: Yes, I do not know the answers to these problems and I would like to find the solutions. I assumed that this is clear.

Comment: This is not homework, it is a problem encountered in my research. By the way, I am not a student and I do not get homework from anyone (I'm happy with this situation).

Comment: Thank you for clarifying and adding some detail to your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems the following.

I don’t know an answer to Part a), so I say a few words about part b). For the convenience I introduce the function $f(n)$ which is equal to the minimum $m_n-m_1$ which is taken over all increasing finite sequences $m_1,\dots,m_n$ non-negative integers such that the all differences $m_j-m_i$ (where $i<j$) are mutually distinct. By the way, I recently considered a [similar question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1092906/two-closest-sums-of-pairs-of-reciprocals), where all differences $\frac 1{m_i}-\frac 1{m_j}$ have to be mutually distinct.

The function $f(n)$ has a trivial lower bound $f(n)\ge n(n-1)/2$. The situation with upper bounds is much more complex. First of all, the sequence $m_i=2^{i-1}$ yields a bound $f(n)\le 2^{n-1}$. Because the gap between an exponential upper bound and a polynomial lower bound is very large, we try to obtain a polynomial upper bound for $f(n)$. For this purpose we shall search $m_i$ in the form $m_i=(i-1)N+h(i)$ for some special number $N$ and function $h$. We impose the condition $0\le h(i)<N/2$ for each $i$. Assume that there exist numbers $j>i$ and $k>l$ such that $m_j-m_i=m_k-m_l$. Then

$$jN+h(j)-iN-h(i)=kN+h(k)-lN-h(l),$$
$$N(j-i-k+l)=h(k)+h(i)-h(l)-h(j).$$

The absolute value of the right hand side is less than $N$, so both sides are equal to zero:
$$i+k=j+l$$
$$h(i)+h(k)=h(j)+h(l)$$

Now we have to choose the function $h$.

Assume that $h(i)=(i-1)^2$. Then

$$(i-1)^2+(k-1)^2=(j-1)^2+(l-1)^2$$
$$(i-1)+(k-1)=(j-1)+(l-1)$$

$$((i-1)+(k-1))^2=((j-1)+(l-1))^2$$

So 
$$2(i-1)(k-1)=((i-1)+(k-1))^2-(i-1)^2-(k-1)^2+$$ $$((j-1)+(l-1))^2-(j-1)^2-(l-1)^2=2(j-1)(l-1).$$

Therefore both pairs $\{i-1,k-1\}$ and $\{j-1,l-1\}$ are roots of a square equation

$$x^2-(k-1+i-1)x+(k-1)(i-1)=0.$$

Therefore $\{i-1,k-1\}=\{j-1,l-1\}$.

In order to $0\le h(i)<N/2$ for each $i$ we have to put $N=2(n-1)^2+1$. Then we obtain $$f(n)\le m_n-m_1=m_n=(n-1)(2(n-1)^2+1)+(n-1)^2=$$ $$(n-1)(2(n-1)^2+n)=(n-1)(2n^2-3n+1).$$

Similarly we can proceed by putting $h(i)=(i-1)^2 \pmod p$, where $p\le N/2$ is an odd prime number. Then we have an equality of pairs $\{i-1,k-1\}$ and $\{j-1,l-1\}$ of residues mod $p$. So if $p\ge n$ then it implies the equality of the pairs $\{i-1,k-1\}$ and $\{j-1,l-1\}$. [We can choose such prime number $p\ge n$ of asymptotic order $n(1+o(1))$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/447334/asymptotics-of-the-lower-approximation-of-a-pair-of-natural-numbers-by-a-coprime) and we may put $N=2p$. Thus we obtain a bound $$f(n)\le 2(n-1)p+p-1=2np-p-1=2n^2+O(n^2).$$

Also we can to build the sequence $\{m_i\}$ consecutively, starting from $m_1=0$ and at each step take as $m_n$ the smallest number such that all differences $m_j-m_i$ $(i<j)$ are distinct (since there are at most $n{n \choose 2}$ forbidden values for $m_n$, we have $m_n\le n{n \choose 2}$). In such a way we obtain

$$\{m_i\}=0,1,3,7,12,20,30,44,\dots.$$

This is [Sequence A025582](http://oeis.org/A025582) from The On-Line Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences.

$$m_i$$

[image]

Empirical evidence suggests that this sequence grows asymptotically as $n^{11/4}$.

$$\frac{m_i}{i^{11/4}}$$

[image]

Answer (score 4):

For **(a)**, you can only find integers $m_i$ such that

$$
\{m_j-m_i\}_{1\le i<j\le n}=\Bigl\{1,2,\dots,\frac{(n-1)n}{2}\Bigr\}
$$

if and only if $n \leq 4$. The proof is by construction. Fix $n$ and let $M = \{m_i\}$ and $D$ be the set of differences induced by $M$. Without loss of generality start with $M = \{0\}$. We proceed by adding elements to $M$ such that we cover the next largest difference not in $D$. To start, we cover ${n \choose 2}$ by adding it to $M$, so $M = \left\{ 0, {n \choose 2} \right\},\; D = \left\{ {n \choose 2} \right\}$. For notational convenience, I simply use $\pm c$ to denote ${n \choose 2} \pm c$, so instead I write 
$$M = \{ 0,-0\}, \;\; D = \{-0\}$$ 
The next difference we try to cover is -1. There are only two possibilities we can add to $M$, namely 1 or -1. By symmetry we can pick either without any loss of generality. So 
$$M=\{0,1,-0\}, \;\; D=\{1,-1,-0\}$$
The next difference to cover is -2, and there are three possibilities 2,-2,-1. However, we must keep $|D| = {|M| \choose 2}$, so we cannot add any element to $M$ that induces a difference already in $D$. In other words, we cannot have $\,m_i\!-\!m_j = \,m_k\! -\! m_l = x\,$ for different pairs $(i,j)$ and $(k,l)$. So 2 and -1 don't work and we are forced to add -2 to $M$.

$$ M = \{0,1,-2,-0\},\;\; D = \{1,2,-3,-2,-1,-0\} $$

The next difference to cover is -4. The possibilities are 2,4,-4,-3 but by the same argument we are forced to choose 4.

$$ M = \{0,1,4,-2,-0\}, \;\; D = \{1,2,3,4,-6,-4,-3,-2,-1\} $$

The next difference to cover is -5, and we find nothing works and we are stuck. Because our choices up until this point were either forced or wlog, we are done. We have found constructions for $n=2,3,4$, and have showed there is no $M$ for $n \geq 5$ (since it is impossible for $M$ to cover $\{-5,-4,-3,-2,-1,-0\}$).

Comment: Nice proof. Thank you. Maybe a similar approach can be considered for the second problem. For the moment I am working on some examples trying to find a pattern.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is a special case of the turnpike reconstruction problem ([wikipedia on related problems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NP-intermediate)), which is concerned with finding a set of distinct positive integers $M = \{m_{1}, m_{2}, \dots m_{n}\}$ already given the set of pairwise differences $\Delta{M} = \{m_{i} - m_{j}\}_{1 \leq i \leq n, \ 1 \leq j \leq n}$ (note that this includes positive and negative differences, mostly for convenience).

This problem is usually approached from a computational perspective: how can we find the set $M$ most efficiently from $\Delta{M}$. One approach is to convert the problem into that of factoring polynomials. Particularly, given a symmetric polynomial
$$
q(x) = \sum_{k = -\alpha}^{\alpha}{a_{k} x^{k}}
$$
we can find a polynomial
$$
p(x) = \sum_{i = 1}^{n}{x^{m_{i}}}
$$
such that
$$
p(x)p(x^{-1}) = \left(\sum_{i = 1}^{n}{x^{m_{i}}}\right)\left(\sum_{i = 1}^{n}{x^{-m_{i}}}\right) =  q(x)
$$
In this case, the set $\{k: a_{k} \not = 0\}$ is exactly $\Delta{M}$, the pairwise differences.
Thus we have
$$
q(x) = \sum_{k \in \Delta{M}}{a_{k}x^{k}} = \left(\sum_{i = 1}^{n}{x^{m_{i}}}\right)\left(\sum_{i = 1}^{n}{x^{-m_{i}}}\right) = p(x)p(x^{-1})
$$
The question of whether this has a solution comes down to determining two things:
what the $a_{k}$ are, and when we can factor certain symmetric polynomials.
This may or may not be easier to determine.

To illustrate with your example of $\Delta{M} = \{-3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3\}$,
$$
(x^{1} + x^{2} + x^{4})(x^{-1} + x^{-2} + x^{-4}) = (x^{-3} + x^{-2} + x^{-1} + 3x^{0} + x^{1} + x^{2} + x^{3})
$$
Note that the coefficient of $x^{0}$ is $3 = n$. Indeed, this holds generally as $x^{0}$ can only occur as the product of $x^{m_{i}}$ and $x^{-m_{i}}$. The other $a_{k}$ are not quite as direct but they likely follow a typical pattern for $\Delta{M} = \{0, \pm 1, \pm 2, \dots \}$.

Comment: Thank you very much for your interesting answer. I will award it with a vote, but I will keep the problem open hoping that something more related to my particular case appears. In fact, for problem (a) I need solutions for arbitrarily large n's, if they exist. If not, I would be extremely interested in solutions for problem (b), also for arbitrarily large n's.

Comment: @aly I realize it is not a full solution, but it was mainly intended as an addition to more specific answers. However, I may edit it later to include more about the particular problem (most of the reason I did not initially was due to the unanticipated issue of finding the coefficients $a_{k}$ in the polynomial).

Answer (score 3):

Your second problem is known as finding [optimal Golomb rulers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Golomb_ruler). Your first problem is known as finding perfect Golomb rulers and, as Drew has shown in [another answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/1145314/revisions), these only exist for $n \leq 4$.

Comment: Cool, I've never heard of these before so thank you.